# How to show how many items for a unique type is in a "Cart" array in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am asking for a little bit of help. I have a food menu List, with a + button on the right side. When the "+" button is pressed, the data from the list is sent to Core Data, and in another is made a fetch request to display them.

***What I want to accomplish :***

- For each product, to have a view like " Menu of the day VEGAN quantity : x1 ", " Water quantity : x1

***What I tried  :***
-I will show my code and I will explain step by step :

**This is My Core Data ViewModel** " func addTask" is used for " When the user press the + button on the right side of the menu, is added to Core Data "

```
class CoreDataViewModel : ObservableObject {
    let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
    @Published var savedCart: [Cart] = []
    lazy var countDictionary = savedCart.reduce(into: [:]) {
        $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
    }
    lazy var savedCartToShow = Array(OrderedSet(savedCart))
    init() {
        
        fetchData()
    }
    func fetchData() {
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Cart>(entityName: "Cart")
        do {
            savedCart = try manager.context.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching \(error)")
        }
    }
    func saveContext() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.save()
            self.fetchData()
        }
        }
   public func addTask(name: String, grams: Double, price: Int ) {
       let newCart = Cart(context: manager.context)
        newCart.name = name
        newCart.grams = grams
        newCart.price = Int32(price)
        saveContext()
    }
```

**This is my Food Menu View**, where the food menus are listed.

```
   ForEach(filteredMenus) { men in
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemMenuView(meniu: men)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text(men.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(men.price) lei")
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                
                                Text("\(men.ingredients.map({$0.grams}).reduce(0, +), specifier: "%.0f")g")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.onboardingColor)
                                .padding(20)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    coreDataViewModel.addTask(name: men.name, grams: men.ingredients.map({$0.grams}).reduce(0, +), price: Int(men.price))
                                }
                        }
                }
```

**This is my Cart View**, where i fetch the items from Core Data and display them, but instead, of seeing the Name and the quantity , all i see is " 1 " for every item in the Cart. [Cart Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIvGX.png)

```
ForEach(coreDataViewModel.savedCartToShow) { car in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("healthyMeal")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .padding()
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                                Text("\(coreDataViewModel.countDictionary[car] ?? 0)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                // .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(car.price) lei")
                                        .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                                    
                                    Text("\(car.grams , specifier: "%.0f") g ")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
```

What can i do to make it work ?

Comment: Look into grouping, fetching with a predicate, or a sectioned fetch request. You’ve included a lot of code but it does not add up to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: Your issue could be due to the `lazy var countDictionary` that is evaluated only once.
Try replacing this, with a computed property, such as:
    `var countDictionary: [Cart : Int] {
        return savedCart.reduce(into: [:]) {
            $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
        }
    }`

Comment: @workingdog I've tried it right now but same behaviour :(

Comment: I noticed you also use `lazy var savedCartToShow`. My understanding with 
lazy var, is that they are evaluated once, the first time they are used.
They are different to computed properties where they are evaluated 
every time they are used. In your case, this is what you want, take into account 
the current value of `savedCart`.